# Why is accessToken field of acquireTokenSilent response is always empty?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an SPA application and authenticate user into Azure AD-B2C via msal-browser.js.

The flow has two sequential calls:

1. `msalInstance.loginPopup(loginObj)`
2. `msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenObject)`

According to the document below, loginPopup should return an idToken and acquireTokenSilent an access_token.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md.

No matter what I do, *accessToken* field is always empty.

I have tried the default and explicitly set permissions of an application in B2C, but it does not make any difference: accessToken is always empty.

`const loginObj = {scopes: ["openid", "profile", "offline_access"]};`

`const tokenObject = {scopes:["openid","https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All"]};`

Can someone explain the reason?

*PS: msal-browser.js v. 2.33*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to request a scope that points to some resource app registered in the directory, second, that resource app must be something you own, so it won’t work with `user.read.all`, since that’s a resource owned by Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app

Comment: Thank you Jas Suri for pointing to the reason: there must be an exposed API, with permission to read, and SPA app needs to be granted a consent to use it.

Step 2 in the manual describes the process of registering BOTH spa and api.

I have got a working accessToken now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are few thigs that you should ensure

1. Verify that your app is setup for PKCE flow. To ensure go to App registration --> authentication and check that you are suing SPA as your platform. Since you are using MSAL.js you need to have SPA as your platform
2. Scope : Make sure you are passing scope when requesting for auth code
   i noticed that for loginObj  you are passing openid, profile, offline_access as scope where as tokenObject has different scope. Try to make them consistent.
3. This is very important, i see that one of your scope is https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All. This scope requires admin consent, not sure if admin consent is granted or not. If Admin consent is not granted and you are requesting a access token with this scope then also it wont work.

[image: Admin-consent-required]

If this did not solve then if possible then share app registration manifest content. It can help us trouble shoot.

Hope this helps!